# Count number of scripts running and wait for them to finish

Tags: powershell, batch-file

I'm looking for the best way to count the number of PowerShell scripts that are currently running.

I run .ps1 scripts from windows batch files. The script I am working on now is launched when a particular email is received from a client - but I want this script to first of all check that no other scripts are busy running at the moment, and if they are it must wait for them to finish before it continues.

I'm sure there are a few ways to go about this, but what would be the safest? I am still learning.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If it is possible to move away from batch files to launch PowerShell then I would suggest using [Start-Process](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh849848.aspx) to launch your scripts.  This will allow you to wait for your processes to exit using [where-object](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee177028.aspx) and [Measure-Object](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh849965.aspx) to filter the scripts that have not yet completed.

So your script might look something like this:

```
# create a loop 
foreach ($item in $reasontoloop) {

    $arguments = "define script names and arguments"

    # Start the powershell script
    $procs += Start-Process powershell -PassThru  -argumentlist $arguments
}

Write-Host -message "Waiting for Processes to complete" 
while( $procs | Where-Object { $_.hasExited -eq $false } )
{
    # Display progress
    $measureInfo = $procs | Where-Object { $_.hasExited -eq $true } | Measure-Object
    write-host "$($measureInfo.count) of $($procs.Length) still running" 

    Start-Sleep 1
}
Write-Host -message "Processes complete"
```

If you are simply interested in the number of PowerShell instances executing then the following one liner using [Get-Process](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh849832.aspx) will help.

```
@(Get-Process | where-object {$_.ProcessName -like 'powershell'}).count
```

Comment: I think I'll go with the one-liner - I can use that to loop until there are no other PowerShell scripts running, and then continue.